# Hallar el total a pagar usando displayTag en Java Web

Tags: java, java-ee

Buenas tardes.

Tengo esto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi consulta es que quiero hallar el total a pagar, obviamente la lógica es sumar todos los subtotales que hay, pero ese total a pagar quisiera que se aumente como un:

```
       <display:column/>
```

Para el SubTotal estoy usando Wrapper:

```
       public String getSubtotal(){

        ReservaDTO r = (ReservaDTO) getCurrentRowObject();

        double pre = r.getPrecio();
        int cant = r.getCant();


        return (pre*cant)+ " Soles";
}
```

De este displayTag sale lo que está en la primera imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Eso se puede hacer con Javascript. ¿Ya lo intentaste? Solo iteras las filas extrayendo el total y la cantidad. Cuando ya tengas el total neto con la cantidad total, añades una fila a la la tabla y muestras los totales. No necesitas displatTag.

Comment: pega el codigo de la vista que sera mas facil crear la funcion javascript... si tienes que persistir y necesitas hacerlo en java, concreta `:)`

Comment: @Mitsu existe `<display:footer>`. No hay necesidad de utilizar JavaScript.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza solo lo comenté como una opción. Además, `displaytag` no tiene actividad desde el 2008...

Comment: @Mitsu 2010. Sí, es antiguo pero hay proyectos donde aún se utiliza, así que hay que aprovechar los beneficios que aún tiene hasta que lo reemplacen por herramientas con más beneficios y flexibilidad.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar `<display:footer>` al final de tus `<display:column` para agregar una fila al pie de la tabla mostrando la información sumarizada.

```html
<display:table ... >
    <display:footer>
        <td colspan="3">Total:</td>
        <td><c:out value="${totalReserva}" /></td>
        <td></td>
    </display:footer>
</display:table>
```

Donde el valor de `totalReserva` lo calculas antes de renderizar tu página.